# how to deal with proxy() object via lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

I need to save some data in a param via Js. When I try to reuse the data, the param I get would be a proxy() obj, and I can not access the data of it.
For example:
in my .js file:

```
@track
historyData = []

method() {
  var item = {}
  item.id = 'a'
  item.data = 'xxx'
  this.historyData.push(item)
} 

get() {
  // here I get a proxy() object, the data is saved in originalTarget.
  this.historyData.find(item => item.id === 'a').data 
}
```

[image]

any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is how LWC or as a matter all Lightning components work.

Your code works fine. I created a button to check and it gave correct `xxx`

```
@track
historyData = []

connectedCallback() {
    this.pushToHistory();
}

pushToHistory() {
    var item = {};
    item.id = 'a';
    item.data = 'xxx';
    this.historyData.push(item);
}


handleButtonClick() {
    this.historyData.find(item => item.id === 'a').data;
}
```

Your code might be breaking elsewhere.